# How exactly array type is stored in C?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

So I've been reading Brian W. Kernighan and Dennis M. Ritchie's "The C Programming Language" and everything was clear until I got to the array-to-pointer section. The first thing we can read is that by  definition, `a[i]` is converted by C to `*(a+i)`. Okay, this is clear and logical. The next thing is that when we pass an array as a function parameter, you actually pass the pointer to the first element in that array. Then we find out that we can add integers to such a pointer and even it is valid to have a pointer to the first element after the array. But then it's written that we can subtract pointers only in the same array. 
So how does C 'know' if these two pointers point to the same array? Is there some metainformation associated with the array? Or does it just mean that this is undefined behavior and compiler won't even generate a warning? Is array stored in memory as just ordinary values of the size of an array type, one after another, or is there something else?

Comment: It doesn't. No. Yes (though some compilers may be smart enough to warn in some limited cases). Yes..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One reason the C standard only defines subtraction for two pointers if they are in the same array is that some (mostly old) C implementations use a form of addressing in which an address consists of a *base address* plus an *offset*, and different arrays may have different base addresses.

In some machines, a full address in memory may have a base that is a number of segments or other blocks of some sort and an offset that is a number of bytes within the page. This was done because, for example, some early hardware would work with data in 16-bit pieces and was designed to work with 16-bit addresses, but later versions of hardware extending the same architecture would have larger addresses but would still use 16-bit pieces of data in order to keep some compatibility with previous software. So the newer hardware might have a 22-bit address space. Old software using just 16-bit addresses would still behave the same, but newer software could use an additional piece of data to specify different base addresses and thereby access all memory in the 22-bit address space.

In such a system, the combination of a base *b* and an offset *o* might refer to memory address 64•*b* + *o*. This gives access to the full 22 bits of address space—with *b*=65535 and *o*=63, we have 64•*b* + *o* = 64•65535 + 63 = 4,194,303 = 2<sup>22</sup>−1.

Observe that many locations in form can be accessed by multiple addresses. For example, *b*=17, *o*=40 refers to the same location as *b*=16, *o*=104 and as *b*=15, *o*=168. Although the formula for making a 22-bit address could have been designed to be 65536•*b* + *o*, and that would have given each memory location a unique address, the overlapping formula was used because it gives a programmer flexibility in choosing their base. Recall that these machines were largely designed around using 16-bit pieces of data. With the non-overlapping address scheme, you would have to calculate both the base and the offset whenever doing address arithmetic. With the overlapping address scheme, you can choose a base for an array you are working with, and then doing any address arithmetic requires calculating only with the offset part.

A C implementation for this architecture can easily support arrays up to 65536 arrays by setting one base address for the array and then doing arithmetic only with the offset part. For example, if we have an array `A` of 1000 `int`, and it is allocated starting at memory location 78,976 (equal to 1234•64), we can set *b* to 1234 and index the array with offsets from 0 to 1998 (999•2, since each `int` is two bytes in this C implementation).

Then, if we have a pointer `p` pointing to `A[125]`, it is represented with (1234, 250), to point to offset 250 with base 1234. And if `q` points to `A[55]`, it is represented with (1234, 110). To subtract these pointers, we ignore the base, subtract the offsets, and divide by the size of one element, so the result is (250-110)/2 = 70.

Now, if you have a pointer `r` pointing to element 13 in some other array `B`, it is going to have a different base, say 2345. So `r` would be represented with (2345, 26). Then, to subtract `r` from `p`, we need to subtract (2345, 26) from (1234, 250). In this case, you cannot ignore the bases; simply working with the offsets would give (250−26)/2 = 112, but these items are not 112 elements (or 224 bytes) apart.

The compiler could be altered to do the math by subtracting the bases, multiplying by 64, and add that to the difference of the offsets. But then it is doing math to subtract pointers that is completely unnecessary in the intended uses of pointer arithmetic. So the C standard committee decided a compiler should not be required to support this, and the way to specify that is to say that the behavior is not defined when you subtract pointers to elements in different arrays.

Answer (score 0):

> ... it's written that we can subtract pointers only in the same array.
>   So how does C 'know' if these two pointers point to the same array?

C does not know that. It is the programmer's responsability to make sure about the limits.

```
int arr[100];
int *p1 = arr + 30;
int *p2 = arr + 50;
//both p1 and p2 point into arr
p2 - p1; //ok
p1 - p2; //ok
int *p3 = &((int)42); // ignore the C99 compound literal
//p3 does not point into arr
p3 - p1; //nope!
```